# Javascript error: setAttribute is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, and I am trying to run the below sample code for a Memory Cards Game from a online tutorial. All the code is inside the event listener: DOMContentLoaded. My HTML Page body is:

```
<body>
    <h3>Score: <span id="result"></span> </h3>
    <div class="grid">          
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.grid{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
}
```

And my event listener code in the JS File is:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
const cardArray = [
        {
            name: 'blank',
            img: 'images/blank.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'cheeseburger',
            img: 'images/cheeseburger.png'
        },        
        {
            name: 'fries',
            img: 'images/fries.png'
        },        
        {
            name: 'hotdog',
            img: 'images/hotdog.png'
        },        
        {
            name: 'icecream',
            img: 'images/icecream.png'
        },        
        {
            name: 'milkshake',
            img: 'images/milkshake.png'
        },        
        {
            name: 'pizza',
            img: 'images/pizza.png'
        },        
        {
            name: 'white',
            img: 'images/white.png'
        }       
    ];
 cardArray.sort(() => { 0.5 - Math.random()});  

 const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
 var resultDisplay = document.querySelector("#result");
 var cardsChosen = [];
 var cardsChosenId = [];
 var cardsWon = [];

 function createBoard(){
     for(let i=0; i < cardArray.length; i++){
         var card = document.createElement("img"); 
         card.setAttribute("src","images/blank.png"); 
         card.setAttribute("data-id",i);
         card.addEventListener("click",flipcard);
         grid.appendChild(card);  
     }
 }

function flipcard(){  
    var cardId = this.getAttribute("data-id");
    cardsChosen.push(cardArray[cardId].name);
    cardsChosenId.push(cardId);
    this.setAttribute('src',cardArray[cardId].img); 
    if(cardsChosen.length === 2){
        setTimeout(checkForMatch,500); 
    }

}

function checkForMatch(){
    console.log("Starting checkForMatch()..........");
    var cards = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    const optionOneId = cardsChosenId[0];
    const optionTwoId = cardsChosenId[1];
    if(cardsChosenId[0] === cardsChosenId[1]) {
        //if(optionOneId === optionTwoId) {
  
        alert("Congratulations: You have found a Match");
        cards[optionOneId] = setAttribute("src","images/white.png");
        cards[optionTwoId] = setAttribute("src","images/white.png");
        cardsWon.push(cardsChosen);
    }
    else {

        cards[optionOneId] = setAttribute("src","images/blank.png"); //ERROR: Uncaught ReferenceError: setAttribute is not defined
        cards[optionTwoId] = setAttribute("src","images/blank.png");
        alert("Sorry: Please try again");
    }
    cardsChosen = [];  
    cardsChosenId = [];
   
    console.log("cardsWon.length is:    " + cardsWon.length);
    resultDisplay.textContent = cardsWon.length;
    if(cardsWon.length === cardArray.length/2){ 
        resultDisplay.textContent = 'Congratulations:: You have found them all';
    }

    document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = resultDisplay.textContent;

}
 createBoard();
});
```

While debugging, the images in the cardArray[] is getting displayed. However, the chrome console is also giving me a strange error in checkForMatch() which I am unable to solve . The error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: setAttribute is not defined
```

The code is running fine on the online tutorial. But I am not sure what mistake I am making here.
Appreciate your help in this matter.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see a setAttribute function in the code, but you're calling it sometimes as "this.setAttribute" and other times without "this"... so that could be the problem ;-)

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda "setAttribute" is JS built-in function so it is not required to declare in anywhere in code.

Comment: setAttribute belongs to Element... isn't it?

Comment: So it should generate error because "setAttribute" is method so object required here. You can't use this method as a independent functions.

Comment: That's the point, she's calling setAttribute as is... is a built-in function of Element.

Comment: Thank you guys for the knowledge. However don't understand why -1 was given to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setAttribute` function belongs to a DOM Element. In this case you're trying to set a value of an image. You should do:

```
cards[optionOneId].setAttribute("src","images/blank.png");
```

The `setAttribute` function itself doesn't exist. It belongs to the Element class.